# AdMob Direct sold ads not displaying

Tags: java, android, admob, advertisement-server

I am using AdMob with a Interstitial and an Banner unit in my Android app.

Now I want to display an Direct sold campaign to these units. So I am using the AdMob campaign section to achieve this. I have created a Ad as an Direct Sold.

I have filled the details and provided the link and all the targeting info and also selected the formats and units.

But after the AD is enabled the status of the Ads is showing as the image below and also the impressions and clicks are showing as zero and the ad in not being show and only the normal ads/other ads are being shown where as I have selected that 100% of the traffic from my country should be shown this ad only. It has already been 2-3 day after creating this.

[image]

I have already filled all the payment details in fact I have already received the payment twice or thrice.

**Any help on how to rectify this or is there any other alternative would be really appreciated.**

Answer (score 1):

Finally found an answer to this one. I had my Direct Sold ads set at 100% of impressions (also also tried setting the eCPM value very high) but only random AdMob ads would show up during testing.

AdMob support let me know that Direct Sold Campaigns require forecasting what your traffic will be in the future in order for it to display them correctly. If AdMob does not detect enough traffic (like when you are only testing the functionality locally) then the Direct Sold ads may never show up.

If you can get enough beta testers using your app for a few days, then the Direct Sold campaigns should eventually kick in.

Personally, I think this is a terrible way to have developers test their direct sold ads, because they cannot be tested, and needs to be fixed by AdMob.